# .select2() is showing the original and select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm currently using Select2 for my dropdown. When I initiate the dropdown, it renders the original dropdown and the select2 dropdown. How can I fix this?

```js
$('#itemSelect1').select2();
```

```html
<select class="itemSelect1">
  <option value="">Select an item</option>
  <?php if (!empty($material)) {?>
    <?php foreach ($material as $key => $value) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $value['material_unique_key']; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $value['material_price']; ?>">
        <?php echo $value['material_name'] ?>
      </option>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

[image: Two select boxes appear]

Comment: The problem is because you've only included the select2.js file, not the additional CSS file. Read the installation guide: https://select2.org/getting-started/installation

Comment: Turns out that was the issue, thanks Rory!